# BGW multiplication by Gennaro et al.: Why does H(x) have exactly degree t and why is $2t + 1 \le n$ necessary?

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation, threshold-cryptography

With this question I am referring to the BGW multiplication by Gennaro et al (PDF [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.27.3164&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).
The multiplication is described on the 4th page.
(Another source for me was ["A pragmatic Introduction to Secure Multi-Party Computation"](https://securecomputation.org/docs/pragmaticmpc.pdf) p. 43-44)

**Summary of BGW Multiplication Procedure**:
To do the multiplication of 2 secret values $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of every player $P_i$ has to have the share $f_{\alpha}(i)$ and $f_{\beta}(i)$ where $f_{\alpha}$ and $f_{\beta}$ are the random degree t polynomials from the Shamir secret sharing.
Now every player $P_i$ computes $f_{\alpha}(i) \cdot f_{\beta}$ and sends shares of this value $h_i(j)$ created with the random degree t polynomial $h_i$ (so that $h_i(0) = (f_{\alpha} \cdot f_{\beta})(i)$) to player $P_j$ for $1 \le j \le n$.

Next the paper from above describes how the players can obtain random degree t shares of the value $\alpha \cdot \beta$ (so that they can then reconstruct the result of the multiplication with these shares):
Every player $P_i$ computes the value $H(i)$ from the degree t polynomial $H$ which is defined as:

$$H(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i h_i(x)$$

($the \lambda_i$s are the appropiate Lagrange coefficients).

$H$ is a random polynomial with

$$H(0) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i h_i(0) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i (f_{\alpha} \cdot f_{\beta})(i) = (f_{\alpha} \cdot f_{\beta})(0) = \alpha \cdot \beta$$

**My Question**: Is H(x) really of degree t? Couldn't it also be bigger because $n$ points from **different** degree t polynomials $h_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$ are used for the interpolation? Usually it is argued that linear operations on $(t,n)$ shared shares result in new $(t,n)$ shares and because the $h_i$ functions are of degree $t$ linear combinations of values $h_i{j}$ for $1 \le i \le i$ should result in $(t,n)$ shares as well. Does this also hold in this scenario, since we always combine values from different degree $t$ polynomials at the same $x$ value?

**Another question**: It is also noted that $t$ hast to be such that $2t+1 \le n$. Is this really necessary? Wouldn't $t+1 \le n$ suffice because $H(x)$ is degree $t$ anyways or is the information from 2t+1 shares necessary to properly construct $H(x)$? (My hypothesis was that, without the $2t+1$ Lagrange coefficients $\lambda_i$, $H(0)$ would no be $\alpha \cdot \beta$)

The "Pragmatic Intro" p. 44 says that only with $2t+1 \le n$ the players have enough information to determine the value $(f_{\alpha} \cdot f_{\beta})(0)$. Why is this the case?

Comment: Welcome to cryptoSE! I think that you mean $2t+1\le n$ rather than $2t+1<n$, but let me know if this is not the case.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. That was exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: $H(x)$ is of degree at most $t$ provided that the players generate $h_i$ of degree $t$. The $\lambda_i$ are constants and so it is a linear combination of polynomials of degree $t$ and so is of degree at most $t$.

For your second question: yes it is necessary. In multiplying shares the group notionally constructs a degree $2t$ product polynomial $q(x)=f_\alpha(x)\cdot f_\beta(x)$ with $2t+1$ coefficients. Player $i$ knows the value of this notional polynomial $q(i)$, and we know $q(0)$ can be written as a linear combination of $n$ of these by cancelling the contribution of higher degree coefficients. Specifically we solve the following system for $\{\lambda_i:1\le i\le n\}$
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
n^{2t}   & (n-1)^{2t}   & (n-2)^{2t}   & \ldots & 2^{2t} & 1\\
n^{2t-1} & (n-1)^{2t-1} & (n-2)^{2t-1} & \ldots & 2^{2t-1}& 1\\
n^{2t-2} & (n-1)^{2t-2} & (n-2)^{2t-2} & \ldots & 2^{2t-2}& 1\\ 
\vdots        & \vdots      & \vdots        & \ddots & \vdots\\
n        & (n-1)        & (n-2)        & \ldots & 2 & 1\\
1             & 1           & 1             & \ldots & 1 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
\lambda_{n}\\\lambda_{n-1}\\\lambda_{n-2}\\\vdots\\\lambda_2\\\lambda_1\end{matrix}\right)=
\left(\begin{matrix} 0\\0\\0\\\vdots\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right)
$$
and deduce that for the $\lambda_i$ that we recover $\sum_i\lambda_iq(i)=q(0)$. To be soluble, this system needs to have at least as many columns as rows so that $n\ge 2t+1$. Note that we can specify $n-(2t+1)$ of the $\lambda_i$ to be zero and still have a solvable system. By inducing the players with $\lambda_i\neq 0$ to act as dealers to share out $q(i)$ using the degree $t$ polynomial $h_i(x)$, the group can notionally construct $H(x)=\sum\lambda_ih_i(x)$ which is a degree $t$ polynomial with $H(0)=q(0)=f_\alpha\cdot f_\beta(0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. Do I understand it correctly then that the constant $\lambda_i$ term is equal to the Lagrange basis polynomial $\delta_i(0) = \prod_{j=1;j \ne i}^{n} \frac{0 - j}{i - j} = \prod_{j=1;j \ne i} \frac{-j}{i-j}$ or is it defined otherwise?

Comment: Yes, the two formulations are equivalent. This can be proven using vandermonde determinants.